# "this" is not what I think it is (from within a prototyped method)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building out a `Controller` function in my Node application. For whatever reason, `this` is not what I think it is from within the prototyped method. I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that `this` would be an instance of the `Controller`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var Controller = function(db) {
    var Model = require('../models/activities.js');
    this.model = new Model(db);
    this.async = require('async');
};

Controller.prototype.getStory = function (activity, callback) {
    console.log(this.model); // undefined
};
module.exports = Controller;
```

Comment: Mike's right, if you're having trouble with things like this see Douglas Crockfords language survey: http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Comment: Can you post the code where you create an instance of `Controller` and call `getStory`?

Answer (score 4):

You never construct an instance of `Controller` in the code you show.

```
module.exports = Controller;
```

is passing the constructor out to client modules, but to construct an instance you would have to do

```
module.exports = new Controller;
```

Alternatively, if you want other modules to create a `Controller` using the exports, they will have to use the `new` operator.

Comment: I didn't provide sufficient context. I am calling this with the `new` operator elsewhere in my code. `this.model` is still undefined.

Comment: @JoshSmith, can you show the code that is creating the instance, and the code that is using the instance?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to read [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) to understand everything related to `this` in JavaScript. I assume you bumped into the following issue (which I can't be sure of, since you didn't provide the code that calls `getStory`):

```
var c = new Controller();

// simple example
var f = c.getStory;
f(); // this.model will probably be undefined

// further examples (easy to bump into when working with Node.js callbacks)
setTimeout(c.getStory, 100);
fs.readFile("/etc/passwd", c.getStory);
```

Since you are using Node.js you can rely on `Function.prototype.bind` to exist (which locks the `this` reference).

```
fs.readFile("/etc/passwd", c.getStory.bind(c)) // should work
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your first line of code:

```
var Controller = function(db) {
    var Model = require('../models/activities.js');
    this.model = new Model(db);
    this.async = require('async');
};
```

This defines a local variable, which is a function. If you are trying to create a constructor, you need to do this:

```
function Controller(db) {
    var Model = require('../models/activities.js');
    this.model = new Model(db);
    this.async = require('async');
};
```

"this" in the context below refers to the outer-most scope, since Controller wasn't a type, rather a local function.

Comment: `function x()` is syntactic sugar for `var x = function()` (with the exception that JS interpreters will look ahead for `function x()` definitions). Every function can be used as a constructor independent of that.

Comment: @MarcelJackwerth That may be true, but this actually fixed the problem. Any idea as to why?

Comment: This definitely shouldn't make a difference, as @MarcelJackwerth said, so maybe you changed something else?

Comment: This seems to be an oddity of the Node.js environment.